# How to become committee member of a conference workshop?

Tags: conference, workshop, program-committee

Is there a formal process behind deciding who should be the members of a workshop committee? Or is it more about the organizers contacting people based on their experience within that particular field?

Comment: The question linked above is asking about conferences, but the principle really is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Organize that workshop
2. Be invited by the organizers to be on the commitee
3. Ask the organizers while the committee is still being formed (and be known and respected by them)

Comment: I can't imagine I would ever be so pushy and directly ask the organizers to put me on the list.